# Elasticsearch: Are RestClient and RestHighLevelClient deprecated in v7.10

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am using **Elasticsearch v7.10**, and in the javadoc, is the following interface

- org.elasticsearch.client.Client

but not the following two classes:

- org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient
- org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient

I am not looking for descriptions of what these classes do, but only want to know whether or not **RestClient** and **RestHighLevelClient** have been deprecated in **v7.10** (current version)?

Thanks

Comment: I was looking for the last two classes in the Server javadoc. I have just found that each is a subproject which has its own separate jar, javadoc, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For people also searching for this, please be aware that at the time of writing the RestHighLevelClient seems to be deprecated. From the documentation this class became deprecated in favor of the [Elasticsearch Java API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/introduction.html)